# Run Google Script from Java app using API, issues with authentication

Tags: java, google-apps-script

I have created a dummy script to avoid scope issues when trying to run it from Java code. Then, I check advanced google services under resources and go to the API console to try to deal with the credentials.

I can see 'Apps Script' credentials have been already created for me. When I try to  set the redirectURI to point an endpoint I am exposing and then save, I get an error message saying I have no rights to perform the action.

Is there any code example to run google scripts from java? I have tried the tutorial but it is not focusing in the authorization. I have been so far able to create the script from java code with the token I get from credentials I have created, but not to run the scripts.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have already tried. Refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi, I have no clue how, but at some point it just worked out. It seems the issue was not in the code, but some permissions missing in the script project. Thanks